# Remapping Vim's default help navigation keybindings

Tags: vim, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I know this may be a newbie question but I can't seem to find it, or make it work.

How do I remap the default keybindings for help files? Basically instead of `<C-]>` to go forward I would like to use `<C-right>`, or use `<C-left>` instead of `<C-t>` etc. Just make it easier to remember.

Of course this should only change if the file is a help file, otherwise it should not make these changes, so that it doesn't conflict with anything.

Thanks for all your help! (Also in the past.)

Comment: What would be the point? These commands are the same whether you edit sourcecode or read the documentation. That makes them easy to remember. Remapping them makes no sense: you would have two mappings that do the same thing in different contexts which would take double the memory in your head for no benefit.

Comment: @romainl I tried `<C-t>` while editing some code and I got "E73: tag stack empty", while in the help I went to the tag I was in before this one (like in a browser and the back arrow). I don't know it's just personal preference. :)

Comment: @Eduan That is because you have not configured ctags or such.

Comment: @ZyX Oh yeah you're right. Well how would I customize these mappings? last time I tried `nnoremap <C-right> <C-]>` and for some reason it didn't work...

Comment: The tag stack is made of all the tags you have jumped to either with `:tag foo` or `<C-]>`. `<C-]>` is used to go to the definition of the "tag" under your sursor. `<C-t>` is used to go back in that tag stack. If you don't use a `tags` file for your coding, both commands are obviously useless for you. But Vim's doc is indexed with `tags` files and `<C-]>`/`<C-t>` work there as they should. Shadowing a super powerful/useful feature because you can't be bothered to learn proper commands is not a very positive thing to do.

Comment: @romainl Yes I understand now, you are right. I posted what I've tried in the past in my previous comment, should this have worked?

Comment: @Eduan You customize these just as usual. But it is not guaranteed that `<C-Arrow>` will work in a terminal. Usually terminals send different things for `<Arrow>` and `<C-Arrow>`, but it may require additional steps for this to work in vim. They work in my vim though, but not in `vim -u NONE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<C-Right>` / `<C-Left>` only in help files if you define the following:

```
" In ~/.vim/ftplugin/help.vim
nnoremap <buffer> <C-Right> <C-]>
nnoremap <buffer> <C-Left>  <C-t>

" Or in ~/.vimrc
augroup HelpMaps
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType help :nnoremap <buffer> <C-Right> <C-]>
    autocmd FileType help :nnoremap <buffer> <C-Left>  <C-t>
augroup END
```

Although I do not think it is a tiny bit useful to do so *only* in help buffers. Such mappings will not possibly interfere with anything but plugins defining their own `<C-Right>`/`<C-Left>` mappings.

Comment: That worked, I think I know why it didn't work before. Mac has predefined mappings for Ctrl+left/right. I solved that adding a shift to it.

Comment: Also, it does work in my Terminal, atleast my iTerm running `xterm-color256`.